# Laravel is giving me Undefined variable Error Exception in views

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have this code:

```
public function lookupTransflow()
{
    //redirect back with data...perform a count on the data n display (1 fills the forms 2 for selct)

    $input=Input::get('search');

    $schools =  Transflow::where('school', 'LIKE', '%'.$input.'%')->get();

    return Redirect::route('search')->with('schools',$schools);

}
```

I'm trying to pass the result to a  this view:

```
 @if(Session::has('schools'))
            @foreach($schools as $school)
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{$school->school}}</a>
           @endforeach
       @endif
```

Please What i'm i doing wrong.

Comment: Could you please add the entire Exception to the question.

Comment: Please check : http://laravel.io/forum/05-22-2014-undefined-variable-laravel-4?page=1

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be confusing data passed to view and data passed to a `Redirect` instance -- which is flashed between requests -- even though you're checking for it correctly inside your view.

My best guess without seeing how you handle your actual `search` route, is that you need to get the `schools` collection from the session in order to use it.

```
@if(Session::has('schools'))
    // $schools is not set, but you can get it directly from Session
    @foreach(Session::get('schools') as $school)
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{$school->school}}</a>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Although, as noted by Martin on the comments, you might want to do this before actually getting into your view. For instance in your `search` route:

```
Route::get('search', function()
{
    $schools = array();
    if (Session::has('schools'))
    {
        $schools = Session::get('schools');
    }

    return View::make('search', compact('schools'));
});
```

If you follow this second suggestion, `$schools` will always be set and you don't have to use the `Session` class inside your view.

Comment: You should **not** be querying the database from views.

Comment: Getting from the `Session` object doesn't imply querying the database. He could do it from a hypothetical `search` route or controller, but he didn't provide enough code to actually append or correct that part, so I just took his code and corrected his mistake...